# ImportError:Using the `Trainer` with `PyTorch` requires `accelerate>=0.20.1`:Please run `pip install transformers[torch]`or`pip install accelerate -U`

Tags: google-colaboratory, importerror, huggingface

I'm using the transformers library in Google colab, and When i am using TrainingArguments from transformers library i'm getting Import error with this code:

```
from transformers import AutoModelForImageClassification, TrainingArguments, Trainer

model = AutoModelForImageClassification.from_pretrained(
    checkpoint,
    num_labels=len(labels),
    id2label=id2label,
    label2id=label2id,
)
training_args = TrainingArguments(
    output_dir="my_awesome_food_model",
    remove_unused_columns=False,
    evaluation_strategy="epoch",
    save_strategy="epoch",
    learning_rate=5e-5,
    per_device_train_batch_size=16,
    gradient_accumulation_steps=4,
    per_device_eval_batch_size=16,
    num_train_epochs=3,
    warmup_ratio=0.1,
    logging_steps=10,
    load_best_model_at_end=True,
    metric_for_best_model="accuracy",
    push_to_hub=True,
)

trainer = Trainer(
    model=model,
    args=training_args,
    data_collator=data_collator,
    train_dataset=food["train"],
    eval_dataset=food["test"],
    tokenizer=image_processor,
    compute_metrics=compute_metrics,
)

trainer.train()
```

This is the error I'm Getting

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-26-cfdcb4612c2d> in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 training_args = TrainingArguments(
      2     output_dir="my_awesome_food_model",
      3     remove_unused_columns=False,
      4     evaluation_strategy="epoch",
      5     save_strategy="epoch",

4 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/transformers/training_args.py in _setup_devices(self)
   1785         if not is_sagemaker_mp_enabled():
   1786             if not is_accelerate_available(min_version="0.20.1"):
-> 1787                 raise ImportError(
   1788                     "Using the `Trainer` with `PyTorch` requires `accelerate>=0.20.1`: Please run `pip install transformers[torch]` or `pip install accelerate -U`"
   1789                 )

ImportError: Using the `Trainer` with `PyTorch` requires `accelerate>=0.20.1`: Please run `pip install transformers[torch]` or `pip install accelerate -U`
```

I already Tried Installing accelerate again and again but same error everytime.
Also used Virtual Evironment still no difference.
And yes both the versions of Accelerte and Transformers are upto date.

```
transformers.__version__, accelerate.__version__
```

These are the versions -> ('4.35.2', '0.27.2')
I'm using Colab environment

Answer (score 1):

I was able to replicate this issue and then solved it by changing the runtime type to T4 GPU. You can do this by going to the settings in the top right corner if you are using colab. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78033871/while-using-seq2seqtrainingarguments-function-this-error-is-displayed-using-th)